# Expose Vue component to outside projects

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to explore how to expose my Vue component to other projects without publishing to NPM.

I am able to find the below link which shows how to publish a Vue component to NPM : [how-to-publish-your-vue-js-component-on-npm-62b67dfb3e58](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-publish-your-vue-js-component-on-npm-62b67dfb3e58)

But I don't want to publish to NPM. Instead, I want to use the created component in another local project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have a private repository in you `package.json`

### Library repo with `.vue` components

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-package-with-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "files": [
    "lib/js/components/**.vue"
  ]
}
```

### Project importing the components

**package.json**

```
{
   "devDependencies": {
      "my-package-with-components": "git+ssh://git@my/repo.git#master",
   }
}
```

**Inside your app, import the .vue files:**

```
import SpecialComponent1 from 'my-package-with-components/lib/js/components/SpecialComponent1.vue';
import SpecialComponent2 from 'my-package-with-components/lib/js/components/SpecialComponent2.vue';

Vue.component('special-component-1', SpecialComponent1);
Vue.component('special-component-2', SpecialComponent2);
```

**Use `npm link` for easier development:**

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link

```
cd mylib/ && npm link
cd ../myapp && npm link mylib
```

Comment: Hi Sander, Instead of adding a GIT Url in Dev Dependencies, can we add direct file link. If so, pls let me know the way to add it. Pls Advice.

Comment: Hey Karth, you can use `npm link` to load a library into npm from directory. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: Thanks Sander, let me try this approach

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for inputs it worked for me. Except the scss functions were not working. For Example @import xxx.scss wont work

Comment: I didn't use any sass/styles in my single file components.

Comment: Any help with npm link. I literally have no idea how to do this. I have /projects/ folder with /project1 and /project2. How do I make project2 use files from project1 using npm link.

Comment: Just to affirm, is `npm link` used to do local development, without relying on a remote repo?

Comment: @MarsAndBack Yes, it can be used just for development